# SQL Select Min By Group and Null when Value does not exist

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (STUDENT int, SCORE int, DATE date)
;
    
INSERT INTO t
    (STUDENT, SCORE, DATE)
VALUES
    (1, 6, '2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2022-03-12 00:00:00'),
    (1, 5, '2022-04-30 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2022-04-12 00:00:00'),
    (2, 0, '2022-04-17 00:00:00'),
    (2, 7, '2022-05-08 00:00:00'),
    (3, 2, '2022-03-16 00:00:00'),
    (3, 3, '2022-03-18 00:00:00'),
    (3, 2, '2022-04-02 00:00:00'),
    (3, 9, '2022-04-27 00:00:00'),
    (4, 4, '2022-02-24 00:00:00'),
    (4, 0, '2022-02-26 00:00:00'),
    (5, 3, '2022-01-28 00:00:00'),
    (5, 0, '2022-02-21 00:00:00'),
    (5, 4, '2022-04-05 00:00:00')
;

SELECT STUDENT, min(DATE) as min_date
from t
where SCORE = 2
group by STUDENT
```

This works but I wish to include ALL 'STUDENT' and if a STUDENT does not have  SCORE = 2 at any time, then the value for DATE is NULL

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT student, MIN(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN date END) AS min_date
FROM t
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY student;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/vuhN0h_s

Comment: thanks a bunch, is there a easy line to add at bottom if for example my coworker needs only STUDENTs with any score = 2?

I try::


SELECT student, MIN(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN date END) AS min_date
FROM t
where exists(score = 2 OVER STUDENT)
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY student;

Comment: Your original query does that. Of course you can add `WHERE score = 2` to my query, but then your `MIN(date)` would suffice and you wouldn't need the `CASE` expression. Another option is to add `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN score = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0` or the like.

Comment: thanks a bunch, may you be able to look at the one I just posted ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1-STUDENT,t2.min_date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT FROM t) t1 LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT STUDENT, min(DATE) as min_date
from t
where SCORE = 2
group by STUDENT) t2 ON t1.STUDENT = t2.STUDENT
```